# Pycharm refactoring member function to __call__(...)?

Tags: python, pycharm, refactoring, automated-refactoring

Lets say I have the following class:

```
class Foo:
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def do_something(self, x):
        return x

bar = Foo()
baz = Foo()
bru = Foo()
print(bar.do_something(3))
print(baz.do_something(4))
print(bru.do_something(5))
```

I want to refactor `do_something` to be the magic function `__call__`, such that the class now looks like:

```
class Foo:
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def __call__(self, x):
        return x
```

Is there a way to accomplish this in Pycharm such that using the refactor tool on `do_something` will refactor `print(bar.do_something(3))` to `print(bar(3))`, in addition to `baz` and `bru` or any other hypothetical calls to that objects `__call__` found in any other part of the project?  Right now it refactors to `print(bar.__call__(3))`

Comment: Search and replace `foo.__call__` with `foo`? :^)

Comment: I have a wide variety of `foo.__call__` that point to the same class type, I'll clarify,

Comment: Actually, couldn't you just search and replace `.__call__` with nothing? You never want to use `.__call__` directly anyway

Comment: ***"using the refactor tool"***: No, you have to use *Search & replace*, using *regex*.

Comment: @C_Z_ I'm not 100% sure that's true, in our codebase we are forced to use `self.__call__()` in places

Answer (score 1):

You can refactor do_something => **call**
and than refactor .**call** => (nothing)

Because all the places that uses **call** use it with dot before,
except from the deceleration that you do not want to delete.